# How to separate debug symbols from a C static library and later load it in GDB

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, static-libraries

I have a static library that is built with object files which have been compiled with "-g" flag. I separate out the debug info of this static library into a separate file such as :
`objcopy --only-keep-debug lib_mylib.o lib_mylib.o.debug`

and then link my application with this static library (after stripping debug info from it) as `gcc -g driver.c -o driver -L. -l_mylib`

Can someone guide how can I load the debug info from the static library from `lib_mylib.o.debug` into GDB so that I can debug the code contributed by static libraries in my application ?
I get below error in GDB when trying to load it via add-symbol-file command:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file lib_mylib.a.debug 0x0
add symbol table from file "lib_mylib.a.debug" at
    .text_addr = 0x0
(y or n) y
`/home/sbunny/tmp/static-lib/lib_mylib.a.debug': can't read symbols: File format not recognized.
```

Comment: At first glance your `lib_mylib.o` has debugging symbols already compiled in, so when you `-l_mylib` those should be included in the final program. Or did you remove them from `lib_mylib.o`?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I stripped the debug symbols from the static library. ```strip -g lib_mylib.a``` before linking with the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug lib_mylib.o lib_mylib.o.debug
```

(It only works for shared libraries.)

Do this instead:

```
cp lib_mylib.o lib_mylib.o.debug
```

Even easier may be to keep `lib_mylib.o` untouched, and strip debug symbols from the executable at link time:

```
gcc -g driver.c -o driver -L. -l_mylib -Wl,-s
```

And easier still: link the binary with debug info and keep it for debugging, but use stripped executable where you need it to be stripped:

```
gcc -g driver.c -o driver-dbg -L. -l_mylib &&
strip -g -o driver driver-dbg
```

With above, you wouldn't need to `add-symbol-file`, just point GDB to `driver-dbg` and it will do everything automatically.

Comment: While the above makes sense, but my use case was to link my executable with a stripped version of the static lib and debug the application as needed. However, whenever needed to debug the static library code being used within the application, I could just load the debug symbols for the static library and continue.

Comment: @sbunny "I could just load the debug symbols for the static library and continue" -- and I told you _exactly_ how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In general, is there a good way to ship debug info for static libraries (comprising of large number of object files) separately then the library itself just like debug info packages of Linux shared libraries.

Comment: @sbunny I don't know of a good way to do that, other than sending the entire unstripped library. It also seems like a contrived use case: why do something manually when doing it automatically (by using unstipped executable) is just as easy?